# Vue CLI Module Federation is component is not found in the Host App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, module, vue-cli

im implementing Module Federation in two Vue CLI Projects

Container App at: http://localhost:8082/
Component App at: http://localhost:8083/
I set up the ModuleFederation plugin in both apps, dont think there is a Problem with That:
Component:

```
plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "data",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        remotes: {},
        exposes: {
            './Bata' : './src/Bata.vue',

        },
        shared: {}
    }),
],
```

Container:

```
plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "appcontainer",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        remotes: {
            "data" : "data@http://localhost:8083/remoteEntry.js" // Test app url see above
        },
        exposes: {},
        shared: {}
    }),
],
```

The components is getting served under: http://localhost:8083/remoteEntry.js:
[image]

The Problem i encounter is when i try to use the component in the Container App:

[image]

It seems like the component is not found, what i noticed tho the request for the container goes to the Container app not to the Component app. Not sure if thats a problem or a normal behavior and something else is not working correctly.

[image]

8082 is the Container app, if i open the same url with 8083 (Component app) the component is there.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind providing a sample repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error if PublicPath is not correct. You can fix this issue by setting it to "auto" as shown below. "auto" will automatically determine the public path.

```
output: {
  publicPath: 'auto',
},
```

Please refer below link for more details [Output | webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath)